# Self-referencing hasMany throws MappingException when a getter returns the same class

Tags: grails

I am wondering if the following scenario is a Grails bug or if there is simply a different way I need to represent the recursive relationship.

Creating a Grails 2.1.0 app (using create-app) and the domain class below (using create-domain-class) yields a MappingException on 'grails run-app':

```
class Person {
    static hasMany = [neighbours:Person]

    public Person getBestFriend() {
        return null
    }
}

Caused by MappingException: Foreign key (FKC4E39B558E488775:person [])) must have same  number of columns as the referenced primary key (person [id])
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

If `getBestFriend()` has a return type of `Object` or any other type, the application starts up fine.  Same goes for changing the `Person` type of the `neighbours` hasMany.  Adding in `static transients = ['bestFriend']` yielded no change.

This exception primarily turned up in my searches when referencing child objects with composite keys, but I was unable to find a situation similar to this example.  Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: Created JIRA for this issue: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9453

Answer (score 0):

I tried here and the same issue happened. One solution is to use [named queries](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html).

```
class Person {

    static hasMany = [neighbours:Person]

    //static transients = ['bestFriend']

    //public Person getBestFriend() {
//      return null
//  }

    static namedQueries  = {
        bestFriend {
        }
    }


    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

Comment: This solution would work if `bestFriend` were an property of `Person`.  Although, it would require exposing GORM methods (list(), get(), etc) to client code which is less than savoury to me.  However, if `getBestFriend()` didn't retrieve a persisted property, say by simply returning `new Person()`, I don't think a named query would suffice.